# Area of a triangle

Tags: python

Trying to find the area of a triangle, the code is pretty simple but whenever I run the code nothing happens, not even the first line of print("width of the base").

```
print("width of the base") 
width = input()
print("height")
height = input()
variable1 = width*height
area = variable1/2
print("area = {0}".format(area))
```

Comment: You need to type a number

Comment: If not even the first line prints, perhaps your stdin (or whatever) is set to a file or something?

Comment: Plus, you need to typecast the input to int to perform operations

Comment: How, EXACTLY, are you running this?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing will only work for a right angled triangle, regardless, i agree with @BuddyBoblll that you need to type a number.
Instead of using the (height*base/2) formula, you can use the Heron's formula, which will need only one or two additional lines of code. Furthermore, it will find area for all types of triangles, and is not restricted to right angled ones.

```
# Three sides of the triangle is a, b and c:  
a = float(input('Enter first side: '))  
b = float(input('Enter second side: '))  
c = float(input('Enter third side: '))  
  
# calculate the semi-perimeter  
s = (a + b + c) / 2  
  
# calculate the area  
area = (s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)) ** 0.5  
print('The area of the triangle is %0.2f' %area)
```

The output that i am getting for this code is:

```
Enter first side: 5
Enter second side: 12
Enter third side: 13
The area of the triangle is 30.00
```

- Side note, i am working on mac osx on a Python 3.8.0 version.